# How can I change this function so that it returns a list of the number of even digits in a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def evens(number_file: TextIO) -> List[int]:
    lst = []
    
    line = number_file.readline().strip()
    while line != '':
        evens = 0
        line = number_file.readline().strip()
        
        while line.isdigit():
            evens = evens + int(line)
            line = number_file.readline().strip()
        lst.append(evens)
        
    return last
```

in this example the file 'numbers.txt' looks like this:

START

1

2

END

START

3

END

START

4

5

6

END

Each line is either an int or 'START' or 'END'
I want to make a function that returns the number of evens in each section so when the code tuns on this file, it should return the list [1, 0, 2]. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Since you're using Python type hinting, I assume this is Python 3 and not Python 2. I suggest you change the tag from `python-2.7`to `python-3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    line = [1,4,5,6,8,8,9,10]
    evens = np.array()
    for l in line:
        if (l % 2) == 0:
            np.append(evens, l)
    return evens

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Without your `txt` file and the code to read it in, this is the best I can do.

Comment: is there any way you can do it by just importing lists and TextIo? I am not familiar with np

Answer (score 0):

When writing new code, it's a good idea to start small and then add capabilities bit by bit. e.g., write code that works without worrying about sections first, then update to work with sections.

But anyway, here's some revised code that should work:

```
def evens(number_file: TextIO) -> List[int]:
    lst = []
    
    line = number_file.readline().strip()
    while line != '':
        evens = 0

        # ignore all text lines
        while !line.isdigit():
            line = number_file.readline().strip()

        # process number lines
        while line.isdigit():
            if int(line) % 2 == 0:
                evens = evens + 1
            line = number_file.readline().strip()

        lst.append(evens)
        
    return lst
```

And here's a version that may be simpler (`for` loops in Python can often make your life easier, e.g. when processing every row of a file):

```
def evens(number_file: TextIO) -> List[int]:
    lst = []

    for row in number_file:
        line = row.strip()
        if line == 'START':
            # new section, start new count
            lst.append(0)
        elif line.isdigit() and int(line) % 2 == 0:
            # update current count (last item in lst)
            lst[-1] += 1

   return lst
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works! Sorry, I'm new to code and I was just wondering does the continue function just extend a line?

Comment: I've updated this since you wrote your comment. You can see a revised version of your code with new parts to skip over text lines and to count even numbers correctly. Then there's my alternative version, which no longer has `continue`. But to answer your question, `continue` in a loop means "skip over the rest of the loop, go back to the top and do the next iteration (if any)".